# Is it possible to install gtkdialog on solaris system

Tags: solaris, gtk

Is it possible to install `GTKDIALOG` on Solaris system?? If somebody has it, let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I've managed to install `Gtkdialog 0.8.3` on `Solaris 11.2` without any issues.

```
wget https://gtkdialog.googlecode.com/files/gtkdialog-0.8.3.tar.gz
tar xvf gtkdialog-0.8.3.tar.gz
cd gtkdialog-0.8.3
./configure
```

At this point, you might run into an error complaining about how no `C compiler` is found. If this is the case, you need to install `GCC` using `sudo pkg install gcc`. After `GCC` installation is complete, continue with the `gtkdialog` installation.

```
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do it on mz Solaris 10 Sparc. I know that there are some diference in GTK for solaris 10 and 11, but I will go with it!!

Comment: I didn't suceed...is it possible to get config.log from you, or something to see..I tried on two Solaris 10, but no luck... I made ./configure with gcc, but also I got so many error...

Comment: What errors are you getting? Post a log and I'll have a look. Sorry for the delayed reply, work's been hectic.